Pass a dynamic date variable into MySQL linked server OPENQUERY
I am using SQL Server v18.10, and try to create a variable for dynamic date and pass it into linked server OPENQUERY. I able to display the date result in SQL but not in linked server.
I followed the way in SQL Server documentation, however the date result I get is showing null which I expected it should be returning the date.
The documentation link as below:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/sql/database-engine/linked-servers/pass-variable-linked-server-query
This is my query and results:
DECLARE @var1 DATE
SELECT @var1 = '2023-01-01'

SELECT * from OPENQUERY(MYSQL ,
'

SELECT @var1
'
)


v18.10 sounds like the version of SSMS? What do you get when you query select @@version?

And you've definitely configured a linked server called MYSQL? Does it work for other operations?

How does what you're doing here relate to the example you linked? The first two examples in the linked page are doing something called SQL Injection to concatenate string segments together to form a complete SQL query. That's bad for security unless you have complete control and validation happening over the tainted user-supplied inputs.

You'll have to use dynamic sql since openquery cannot access variables from outside. @var becomes a mysql session variable which doesn't exist probably. I'd probably use EXECUTE('select ?', @var1) AT MYSQL anyway

I followed the way in SQL Server documentation Actually you didn't. The example is to use dynamic query to call the OPENQUERY. Your query didn't. And your query will not even compile, you should encounter error on @var1. Check the documentation again

Hi @DaleK, yes the v18.10 is the version, while if i change query into @@ver it will give result of unknown system variable as below.
OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "mysql" returned message "[MySQL][ODBC 8.3(a) Driver][mysqld-8.0.33-commercial]Unknown system variable 'var1'".
And for your another question, yes it work for other operations but i not sure how to share the image result at here

Hi @AlwaysLearning,  my original motive was to creating dynamic date pass into my other query which required to use with linked server, so this query was to try whether is it possible to work , my original query was something like below:
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY( MYSQL, '
SELECT v.visit_id AS "Visit S/No.",
date_format (v.visit_date,"%d %b %Y") AS "Visit Date",
c.code AS "Company Code",
c.name AS "Company Name"
FROM visit v
INNER JOIN company c on c.company_id = v.company_id and c.deleted = "N"
WHERE
v.visit_date >= "2024-03-01"
AND v.visit_date <= "2024-03-31"
')

Hi @siggemannen, i shall try that and see if thats work, thanks

Hi @Squirrel, what i understand for this part is, it use linked server (EXEC) to call another linked server (OPENQUERY), or am i understand it wrongly? I will check it again, thank you.

@DaleK, oh ya thanks for pointing out, after i ran it, i get this version
Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP3-CU1-GDR) (KB5029187) - 13.0.7029.3 (X64)   Aug 16 2023 19:44:44   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Standard 10.0  (Build 17763: ) (Hypervisor)

Why use OPENQUERY at all why not just SELECT * FROM MYSQL.SomeDb..SomeTable WHERE date > @dateVariable

Hi @Charlieface, because i dont have direct access to the database, and only able to remote working on it.

@Charlieface, sorry that i missed out something, I had access to read it but no access to write the database, so is it still possible to use four part naming?

hi @Charlieface, i unable to execute it due to i dont have the actual server name, database and schema, the server i had is already a linked server.
I had even try to use it accrordingly as below, but showing object invalid:
[1.123.1.123].[database].[schema].[table]

Hi @Squirrel, i had try go through documentation again for the query and changed as below:
`
DECLARE @query1 VARCHAR(MAX), @date_1 DATETIME
SELECT @date_1= '2024-01-01'
SELECT @query1=
'
SELECT  * FROM OPENQUERY (MYSQL, ''SELECT @date_1, TB.* FROM Tables TB '')
'
EXEC(@query1);
`
the table able to show correct result, but the assigning variable still remain NULL

Why are you using the IP address? Just use the linked server name MYSQL like MYSQL.database.schema.table

@Charlieface, I cant use MYSQL as the server name with or without square brackets, it will display error of could not locate in sysdatabases for database 'MYSQL'. No entry found with that name

Hi @Charlieface, it is not working from my side. I unable to put in four-part naming, i able to get table but not exact name for the database/schema. I had try the SHOW databases;, SHOW SCHEMAS, both return me the same result which is database name which mean i only able to query as below:
SELECT * FROM MYSQL.database.table
but it will provide me invalid object as result, i only able to confirm that table is correct but not for database naming

I think because there is no schema in MySQL you need MYSQL.database..table

Hi @Charlieface, is not working from myside and the error provided as below:
The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "mysql" supplied inconsistent metadata for a column. The column "visit_id" (compile-time ordinal 1) of object "fhn3.visit" was reported to have a "DBTYPE" of 3 at compile time and 19 at run time.

Hmmm what is the type of that column?

for this column visit_id is an integer type

You can't pass in parameter to the OPENQUERY command.
on your query in your last comments

DECLARE @query1 VARCHAR(MAX), @date_1 DATETIME 
SELECT @date_1= '2024-01-01' 
SELECT @query1= ' SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY (MYSQL, ''SELECT @date_1, TB.* FROM Tables TB '') ' 
EXEC(@query1);


It seems that @date_1 has nothing to do with the remote query at all.
if this is the case, you may use return the @date_1 in the outer query and use sp_executesql to pass in the parameter
DECLARE @query1 NVARCHAR(MAX), 
        @date_1 DATETIME 

SELECT  @query1 = ' SELECT @date_1, * FROM OPENQUERY (MYSQL, ''SELECT TB.* FROM Tables TB '') ' 

exec    sp_executesql @query1, N'@date_1 datetime', @date_1

OR use the 4 part name to query from the linked server
SELECT  @date_1, TB.*
FROM    [MYSQL].[DB NAME].[SCHEMA].Tables TB


Hi @squirrel, I try to edit my query from what you had provided as below:
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX); DECLARE @date_1 date; SELECT @date_1 = '2024-01-01'; SELECT @SQL =  ' SELECT top 10 * FROM openquery(mysql, '' SELECT @cols, v.* FROM visit v where v.visit_date >= @date_1 '' ) ' EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@date_1 date', @date_1  
Result showing empty as the variable is still NULL in value, I not sure which part of my query is wrong, need your help to point out.
While for the 4 part naming, I get result of invalid object as i dont have exact naming for database/schema.

You can't pass a parameter to the query in OPENQUERY(). You need to concatenate the date to the query string before passing to OPENQUERY()
